# send SMS asp.net and attach image

Tags: c#, asp.net, sms

I need to be able to attach an image to an SMS message that I am sending from my asp.net app, I found some answers but they are all for Andriod development. HAs anyone done something like this?

Comment: Try to have a look at this link (bottom of page) URL:http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-free-SMS-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx